# Cannot run multiple executions in maven surefire?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to run test classes whose name end with ResourceTest.java, so I defined following execution.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>resource-tests</id>
            <phase>resource-tests</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>resource-tests</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>**/*ResourceTest.java</includes>
                <!-- <exludes>**/*.java</exludes> -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But I'm not sure how to run this, I've searched a lot and I'm missing something.

I tried surefire:test, it skipped all the test cases as defined in above configuration. So, I tried `surefire:resource-tests`, maven is saying no goal is not defined.

I'm using eclipse to run my maven build, by passing these parameters. How can I run by the execution id?

How to select a specific execution when running with surefire:test when I've mulltiple executions defined in my pom?

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several problems with your current configuration :

- you are forcing the `maven-surefire-plugin` to be executed in the `resource-tests` phase but this phase [does not exist](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). You should delete that declaration to keep the default plugin binding phase, which is `test`.
- you are invoking the goal `resource-tests` but `maven-surefire-plugin` [does not define such a goal](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/plugin-info.html).
- the `<includes>` element is ill-defined. There should be a `<include>` tag under it.
- you are excluding all Java files from the plugin configuration so no test will be run
- the configuration of the plugin should be done under the `<configuration>` element not for each `<executions>`.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*ResourceTest.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

When you have multiple executions and you want "select" one of them, you can use a profile:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>resource-tests</id>
        <properties>
            <test-classes>**/*ResourceTest.java</test-classes>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>task-tests</id>
        <properties>
            <test-classes>**/*TaskTest.java</test-classes>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

with the following plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>${test-classes}</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With such a configuration:

- when you run `mvn clean test -Presource-tests`, only the classes matching `**/*ResourceTest.java` will be tested
- when you run `mvn clean test -Ptask-tests`, only the classes matching `**/*TaskTest.java` will be tested

Comment: now I can run this with surefire:test right? when I run like this, I'm seeing String cannot be cast to util.List error for <includes>**/*ResourceTest.java</includes> property. And also, when I specify multiple executions, how can select specfic execution?

Comment: @pinkpanther You can simply run `mvn clean test`. Since this plugin is bound by default to the `test` phase, it will be executed.

Comment: @pinkpanther Yes, I saw this afterwards and edited my post.

Comment: thanks, I also could you tell me how to select a specific execution when I've multiple executions defined? for example, with id=task-tests?

Comment: I updated my question, I'm trying to define multiple executions, hence I asked the question.

Comment: Can it be not done with executions itself? because, point having multiple executions is running them on choice is it not?

Comment: And also it is running other tests also...not sure where the problem is

Comment: @pinkpanther Answer updated. Multiple execution is not for executing them on choice. It is to execute the plugin multiple times.

Comment: I tried with eclipse run as maven build, in the goals section I've given "clean test", in profiles I've given resource-tests. Build was success but it gave [INFO] tests skipped.

Comment: due to the exclude mentioned in configuration level of plugin it is excluding all tests...but if I remove that it is executing all.

Comment: @pinkpanther Yes you need to remove that configuration. I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: But if I remove that, all tests are running but I don't want all tests to be run, I just want the classes included under the particular execution run.

Comment: I'm just surprised this answer hasn't  got at least 200+ yet